# Solving for n in the exponent.

Tags: probability

Well, it's another question I feel like I should know. I'm trying to model the number of successes before the first failure. The probability of successes is given as $p$, which makes the probability of failure $(1-p)$.

The probability mass function, as I've calculated it, turns out to be $p^{n-1}(1-p)$, since we will stop at the first failure.

I'm trying to solve the following equation for n, but I'm at a loss for how to get it out of the exponent.

$1=p^{n-1}(1-p)$

I would appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you everyone--I think I can see my error here. I'm just thrown off by the way he asked the question. The question is about coin flips, and he gave the probability of heads as p. The question is "what is the expected number of tosses before the first tails?" If he gave the probability of tails as p, I think I could get the number of tosses with (1-p)/p, which gives (I think) the number of trials before the first success. It's the wording, and my approaching bedtime, that's throwing me off, I think.  For some reason, I think what I want is p/(1-p), but that may be the tiredness talking.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is the number of **successes** (not trials) until the first failure, then $\Pr(X=n)=p^n(1-p)$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$.

This cannot ever be equal to $1$ if $p\ne 0$.

If you want to solve $p^n(1-p)=a$, given $0\lt p\lt 1$, rewrite the equation as 
$p^n=\frac{a}{1-p}$.
and take the logarithm of both sides.

**Remark:** As was pointed out in the answer, except in the trivial case we cannot have $\Pr(X=n)=1$. Perhaps you want to show that 
$$\sum_0^\infty p^n(1-p)=1.$$
Let $0\lt p\lt 1$. Then the above sum is an infinite geometric series, and by the usuual formula it does sum to $1$. We do not even have to compute, since $\sum_0^\infty \Pr(X=n)$ **must** be $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p^{n-1} (1-p) = 1$ then $p^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-p}$ and so $n-1 = \log_p \frac{1}{1-p}$ and $n = 1+\log_p \frac{1}{1-p}$.

Comment: Thank you everyone--I think I can see my error here. I'm just thrown off by the way he asked the question. The question is about coin flips, and he gave the probability of heads as p. The question is "what is the expected number of tosses before the first tails?" If he gave the probability of tails as p, I think I could get the number of tosses with (1-p)/p, which gives (I think) the number of trials before the first success. It's the wording, and my approaching bedtime, that's throwing me off, I think.

For some reason, I think what I want is p/(1-p), but that may be the tiredness talking.

Answer (score 0):

Using the equation you gave, $1 = p^n (1-p)$

You should get the term with "n" by itself:

$1/(1-p) = p^n$

and then simply take the logarithm

$-log(1-p) = n*log(p)$

$n = -log(1-p)/log(p)$

However, I think that the problem itself might be more complicated than you've realized. It is the sum of all possible values of "n" - not just one of them - from 0 to ∞ that would make the probability equal to 1.

$1 ≠ (p^n)(1-p)$

$1 = (1-p)$$(p^0+p^1+p^2+p^3+p^4+...)$